# How to make glTF and primitive materials work in A-Frame

Tags: aframe, gltf

We've created a simple ruby-coloured cube in Blender 2.8 beta to test glTF material exports.

When looking at it in Don Mccurdy's glTF viewer it looks fine:

[image]

It also looks fine in Windows 10's explorer preview pane.

However, when loading in aframe 0.8.2 it appears black.

To test there wasn't a problem with our scene, we created a primitive cube with a similar material in aframe. This also appears black, *until we open the aframe inspector*, after which it looks like this:

[image]

Here's the github repo: https://github.com/edsilv/aframe-pbr-test/blob/master/index.html

Any thoughts on how to make primitive and glTF object materials appear correctly in aframe are most welcome!

Comment: In my viewer (https://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com/) try using the lighting options to disable (a) ambient light, (b) direct light, or (c) the environment map. Often, a metallic object will be dark unless you have an environment map. If that's the problem, you can add an environment map using the `cube-env-map` aframe component here: https://github.com/donmccurdy/aframe-extras. Unfortunately the `material` component has no effect on models that already have their own materials.

Comment: Changing the metalness to 0 and the roughness to 1 is also a quick fix here, if you don't really want the object to be metallic. :)

Comment: That's working now for the glTF model using your `cube-env-map` component (have updated github repo).
Out of interest it would be nice to get the primitive example working too. Right now I'm including the material like this: 
https://github.com/edsilv/aframe-pbr-test/blob/master/index.html#L18
In your `cube-env-map` docs you specify the material(s) inside the component:
https://github.com/donmccurdy/aframe-extras/tree/master/src/misc#cube-env-map
How you are declaring these materials - reading through the aframe docs I'm not seeing a way to reference materials by name in this way?